# Force return statement on caller function

Tags: php, api, symfony, reflection, httpresponse

I am just curious if it's possible to force parent method to return a value from within method called in that parent method? Let's say I have:

```php
    public function myApiEndpoint()
    {
      // I DO NOT want to to have return statement here
      $this->validOrUnprocessable();

      // some other code

      //return value
      return $someValue;
    }
```

```php
    public function validOrUnprocessable()
    {
       if ($condition) {
         ... here goes the code that forces return statement on myApiEndpoint function without putting the word `return` in front of this call...
       }
    }
```

So in other words `validOrUnprocessable` method, when it needs to do so forces or tricks PHP into thinking that myApiEndpoint returns the value. I do not want to use `return` statement when `validOrUnprocessable` is called or any if conditions.

I do know other ways of doing what I want to do but I wanted to know if something like that is possible. I am not interested in any workarounds as I know very well how to implement what I need to achieve in many other ways. I just need to know if this what I described is possible to do exactly how I described it.

I did try to get there with reflections and other scope related things but so far no luck. Any ideas?

Just to add. I am doing this because I want to check how far I can push it. I am building a tool for myself and I want it to be as convenient and easy to use as possible.

If it's not possible I have another idea but that's a bit out of the scope of this post.

Comment: it's not possible, using methods only

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I am afraid you might be right. I think I do have two ideas though. I will either try to use reflections to override the method and I will invoke it again which should simply return what I want or I will create another internal endpoint that will spit out what I will ask it to spit out. So I will simply redirect to it and that should do the trick but it would be awesome to be able to do that the way I envisioned it :(

Comment: That seems like a bad idea. Why would you want a method call to magically return? And return what, exactly? In your example, `myApiEndpoint()` appears to return a value when things go right. What is the client supposed to expect when that check fails? Exceptions however seem perfectly fit for the job, you don't even have to `try` / `catch` within `myApiEndpoint` and you could just handle them globally somewhere.

Comment: @Jeto thanks for the comment. I explained the context a bit more in comments to answer posted today. I know I can use exceptions but I don't want to. I did not want to go into details because they do not matter as I am not looking for advice on system design and I realise example I provided is out of context so looks a bit strange. I wanted to see for my pet project how much convince I can pack into it. It will return http 422 response. It's all done, nice and neat  and works very well. I was just experimenting with different convinience wrappers and helpers. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Also no matter what I decide to stick with I will always get a bit more insight into details of how PHP works and for that alone it's worth the time spent on experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

You should throw an exception.

```php
    public function validOrUnprocessable()
    {
       if ($condition) {
         throw Exception('foo bar');
       }
    }
```

The code calling this method should be ready to catch an exception:

```
public function myApiEndpoint()
{
  try {
    // I DO NOT want to to have return statement here
    $this->validOrUnprocessable();

    // some other code
    //this code will never be called because of exception thrown in validOrUnprocessable
    return value;
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    //do something else 
    return -1; //you can return another value as example.
  }


  return $someValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I do not want to throw an exception. I know I can but I do not want to do so. I could've done that in `validOrUnprocessable ` function. I want it to work exactly as I described. No exceptions, no if conditions. Just this one single call.

Comment: Just to add your answer is a valid and good way of dealing with that. However just not what I wanted to do.

Comment: @Robert and what `myApiEndpoint` should return if `$condition` is true?

Comment: It's a bit bigger thing. So just to give you some context - I've built for myself a "Symfony API tool" that helps me writing API's in Symfony. This `validOrUnprocessable` should return a Symfony's `422` response(I've built everything I need for that to do it in a clean and neat way). The thing is if I return response in `validOrUnprocessable ` it will just come back to the endpoint and I would have to return it again to make Symfony spit it out. I want to make this super convenient for myself by allowing for just this one function call. I have a nice backup plan but I wanted to try this first.

Comment: I hope it makes sense as just the example might be a bit out of context and might seem to be silly at first sight.

Comment: In all of our endpoints, we issue a `die($json_response);` which has the same effect. The response is handled without control being sent back to the caller function. I would probably re-work your function so that the flow of control is more deliberate.